# Listen to input field using a spring controller

Tags: spring-boot

Is it possible, in our controller, to get realtime input from a user writing in a html textfield? I know its possible to do via eg. jquery/js, but we are students and want a java'ish solution.

Comment: You can do it. But there are two different aspects to it. From frontend you need send a rest call on every key press to the backend. You can use any framework or just simple jQuery ... In the backend you just need to add a controller to accept those requests and serve the results

Answer (score 0):

only using java is impossible because java need communication with the HTML page, you can perform that but you need to use java-script too. for example you can write a controller and call it using Ajax in a event java-script method like keyup.

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/info/")  
public class Controller {

    @RequestMapping(value="/get/",
            method=RequestMethod.POST,
            produces=MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE,
            consumes=MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public Map<String,Object> getInputData(@RequestBody Map<String, Object> data){

        String inputData = data.get("inputValue").toString();
        //TODO

        return data;
    }
}
```

from java-script build your Json response and call /info/get/ rest URL.
for example using axios.

```
axios.post('/info/get/', {
    inputValue: 'your input form data'
  })
  .then(function (response) {
    //todo
  })
  .catch(function (error) {
    // if has errors
  });
```

but otherwise can't be